# MongoDB repo for apt-mirror

Tags: debian, apt, mirroring, repository, mongodb

Must mirror the Debian MongoDB repo for an offline DMZ. Ubuntu works, Debian doesnt. What is wrong here?

Works:

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse
```

Does not work:

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse
```

Comment: “Does not work” is not an error description.

Comment: Processing indexes: [SSSPPPPPPPPPPPPapt-mirror: can't open index repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian//dists/stretch/mongodb-org/3.6/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages in process_index at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 800.
P]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error message is pretty clear, isn’t it?

The correct line would be:

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/3.6 main
```